# Captive portal setup with minimal hardware requirements

Tags: cisco, wifi, captive-portal

I am willing to deploy a captive portal for a free wifi access at my local business. I would like that every customer connecting to my AP be redirected to a web page where I could display some ad for my business. There are no need for credentials beyond admin access, but the access should be protected by a global password (similar to WPA2) that would not change over time. The customers should be forwarded to that website every week or so.

At the moment, there is an old AP (ZyAIR B-3000) deployed without any captive portal feature. There is no server capable of running a local webserver. However I have a website hosted by an external web provider.

There exist many open source solutions referenced in this [blog post](https://mohammadthalif.wordpress.com/2010/12/14/list-of-open-source-captive-portal-software-and-network-access-control-nac/), but all of them require to have some sort of server to enforce network access control.

I have seen that [modern Cisco Small Business wireless AP, such as the WAP321 or WAP561](http://sbkb.cisco.com/CiscoSB/GetArticle.aspx?docid=590450fe7a554eba9f0a44d8dd83779e_Enable_a_Captive_Portal_on_your_Cisco_Wireless_Network.xml&pid=2&converted=0), have some captive portal features. But I do not fully understand whether this would fulfill my needs.

Are there any other solutions that would require a minimal investment in term of hardware and maintenance effort?

Thank you all for your comments and inputs!

Comment: Contact your local Cisco sales rep and have them send over a couple of demo units.

Comment: @CraigWatson So you believe one of these Cisco devices could work?

Comment: Figuring out whether they work is what testing the demo units is for.

Comment: I fully understand your point. If I go to these Cisco "Partners" (which are I believe your local sales rep), I doubt they will simply send me some units to try, and let me buy it afterwards around the corner, will they? Also, they will try to sell me their services and not only the hardware. Cisco is redirecting from their website all queries about SMB solutions to local partners. How can I get them to send me some demo units?
Your help is very much appreciated!